# Does it exist a matrix that multipled by an arbitrary vector performs a specific operation to that vector?

Tags: systems-of-equations

The background of my request is the following: I would need to implement a component that performs an operation f(E) to an arbitrary signal E. The signal is a function of the space E(x), with x going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and the hardware component may occupy all the space.
For the sake of simplicity, I discretize the signal into equispaced pixels $x_l$, with $-\infty<l<+\infty$.

Now, this idea turns into the following practical problem:
I need to understand if there exists a matrix $A_{k,j}$ so that:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k,j=-\infty}^{+\infty}A_{k,j}E(x_{j+l-k})=f(E(x_{l})).
\end{equation}
for every $l$ satisfying $-\infty<l<+\infty$.

As a starting simple case, $f$ may be an operator that returns (i) a constant C, or (ii) the heaviside function $f(E(x_{l}))=H(E(x_{l+1})-E(x_{l}))$. Is there somebody that can tell me if that matrix A exists?

Once I know that such $A$ exists, I have to find it and finally, to perform inverse design to engineer the hardware component. But before putting effort in searching for this matrix, I need to know if it exists.

I here underline that the matrix A should perform that operation f on any arbitrary signal E  because - just to stay to my example - I want the hardware component to perform an heaviside operation applied to the signal whatever is the signal.
Furthermore, if it helps answering my question, I specify that the limits of the space have not to be exactly $\pm \infty$, but they can be also finite, but very big.

Can you help me?
Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards.

Comment: Usually it doesn't exist. The LHS is linear in $E$ (if you amplify a signal or add two signals, the outputs will amplify or add too), but the RHS in your example is obviously not.